Database Normalization [Separating Tables]
When normalizing data from an application form, each applicant will have one spouse. The "Applicant Code" serves as the primary key. Creating a surrogate key seems unnecessary due to their cardinality.
Should I still make a separate table for "Spouse" even if it has a one-to-one relation to the "Applicant"? And if that's the case, is it allowed for two tables to have the exact same primary key?

Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. How are you 1st stuck, following what published DB design method reference? Basic questions are already asked & answered years ago. [ask] [Help] Why do you think a question you are asking here has something to do with DB normalization? How are you applying anything about it?

Normalization is not the crucial topic. It is the usage. If spouse is irrelevant, then there is no need for an extra table.
However if you want to prevent an applicant to solicit to the same department as the spouse ...
I then would have expected even a table for person.
Semantics. A spouse can be an applicant too. Between two forms the marital status may have been changed. It could make sense to keep the data up-to-date and prevent the same spouse occurring twice or the spouse as applicant not having the original applicant as spouse. (Your 1:1 / 1:0). Volatile data like applicant forms however may be short lived, also for legal reasons.
Now deciding the database normalization. Would it not make sense to introduce marriage? In fact a cross-table.
By the way: I see no sense in a functional spouse field. No checks too. And it would be nice not to have a gender field BTW.
(I would rather see some neater reasoning as answer.)

I like to start database entity designs with entities that exist in the physical world. There is generally less debate about what attributes are instinsic to something that physically exists, and the columns don't change very often. In this case, an applicant is a person, and the spouse is a person. The relationship between them is a logical entity.
So, not all person objects are applicants, and applicants can have attributes that not all persons have. Given my druthers, I'd create an extension table for the applicant specific attributes, and expose APPLICANT as a view joining those tables. That way, supposing the applicant becomes an employee, the attributes that they have as a person do not change, and there is only one copy of them. A record can be added to the employee extension table, and their employee records can be exposed through an EMPLOYEE view.
